# StringUtils.isBlank return false for null Strings

Tags: java

I am working in a Java project and my code shows weird behavior. Here is my code:

```
String access = String.valueOf(getStringvalue());
Boolean isBlank = StringUtils.isBlank(access);
```

In the above code, 'access' object can have null values.
And it is said that if we pass a null value to `StringUtils.isBlank()`, it will return true. But here I returned only false value when `access` is null. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: check the implementation of `StringUtils` class. It is from apache common utils?

Comment: If you pass `null` to [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) you get the string `"null"`. That is not null and it is not blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had this problem and found the trick just after saw the source code of String.valueof(). The source code of String.valueof() is below.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Therefore when you pass a null object, you will get a 'null' String. Therefore your StringUtils.isBlank() will treat is as a String rather than a null object and you will get a 'false' booean value.

Hope it helps.!

Comment: No need to look at the source code - this is the documented behaviour of `String.valueOf`. It's not clear why the OP is calling `String.valueOf` at all...

Comment: "null" is a string with 4 characters: n, u, l and l. It's a string, like any other string.

Comment: @JBNizet Nice explanation. So valueOf(null) will return "null" as string ?

Comment: Yes, as documented. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29: *Returns:
    if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"*

Answer (score 0):

I tested those code and they give the same result.

```
 Boolean isBlank = StringUtils.isBlank("");
 System.out.println(isBlank);// give true
```

and

```
 Boolean isBlank = StringUtils.isBlank(null);
 System.out.println(isBlank);// give true
```

Comment: String s1; is not always the same as String s1 = null; Just try and create a String as a local variable, it doesn't get a default value.

Comment: `println(true)` and `println("true")` will print the same thing, though they are different types. If you pass the same two values to `StringUtils.isBlank()`, they will give a different outcome.